# Quasar simple filter select can't filter and emit for dynamic data

Tags: vue.js, quasar-framework

I am trying to have a select component with a simple filtering system. I am getting the initial list in the select input. But while clicking on the select input and writing keywords in order to filter, it's giving the following error and does not filter anything: `Uncaught TypeError: v.toLowerCase is not a function`

```html
<div class="col-6">
  <q-item-label class="q-pl-sm text-weight-bold form-label">Division</q-item-label>
  <q-select filled dense v-model="input.division" use-input hide-selected input-debounce="0"
            class="q-ma-sm" label="Select an Option" :options="options" @filter="filterFn" option-
            value="id" option-label="name" emit-label>
    <template v-slot:no-option>
      <q-item>
        <q-item-section class="text-grey">
          No results
        </q-item-section>
      </q-item>
    </template>
  </q-select>
</div>
```

```js
import {
  ref,
} from 'vue';

export default {
  setup() {
    return {
      options: ref([]),
    };
  },

  methods: {
    getDivisions() {
      this.$axios.get('https://api.bdshsystem.com/public/api/v1/area')
        .then(response => {
          Object.keys(response.data.divisions)
            .forEach(key => {
              this.options = response.data.divisions;
            });
        });
    },

    filterFn(val, update) {
      if (val === '') {
        update(() => {
          console.log(this.getDivisions());
          this.options = this.options;

          // here you have access to "ref" which
          // is the Vue reference of the QSelect
        });
        return;
      }

      update(() => {
        const needle = val.toLowerCase();
        this.options = this.options.filter(v => v.toLowerCase()
          .indexOf(needle) > -1);
      });
    },
  },

  mounted() {
    this.getDivisions();
  },
};
```

Comment: I'm in a weird state of mind about how your code works at all :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your options values are objects, not strings. So in filtering, you should consider that.

```js
this.options = this.options.filter(v => v.name.toLowerCase().indexOf(needle) > -1)
```

Comment: Thanks man, I know my coding is really messy ... trying hard to make it more professonal :)